# Mongoose connect and pool size not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Having issues with my Mongoose connection.  It works in connecting to the database but the pool size seems to be unaffected despite me setting the value.  Am I missing something or is there a different way to know what the new pool size of my connection is?

```
const mongooseOptions = { poolSize:10 };
console.log(mongooseOptions);
mongoose.connect( "mongodb://username:password@host:port/database", mongooseOptions );
console.log(mongoose);
```

Comment: Code looks right. Why do you think it's not being set right?

Comment: Whenever I check the server it only looks like 5 processes are being run.  I can't figure out a way to check and see what the pool size is, the console.log(mongoose) has two places where options appear and PoolSize is not in either one.  

Also, forgot to point out that I'm using Mongoose 5.2.13

Answer (score 0):

The `poolSize` connection option sets the *maximum* size of the pool, so it's normal for a smaller number of connections to created initially, and more connections will be added as needed, up to the maximum configured value.

The documentation for the setting can be found in the native drive docs ([here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/MongoClient.html)), where the setting is described as:

> The maximum size of the individual server pool

Comment: Is there a way to know how many connections have been made at a point in time or to manually request more?

Answer (score 0):

You can check in a `mongo` shell the current number of connections:

```
db.serverStatus().connections
```

Despite setting mongoose `poolSize` to 50, I still only had a maximum of `{ "current" : 7 }` made up of one for the mongo shell, one for MongoDB Compass and the default 5 from mongoose.

What I noticed was that I was passing in the `poolSize` via an environment variable. After calling `parseInt` on the environment variable, my current Connections increased to 25. So make sure that you are actually passing in an integer to the `poolSize` option and not just a string.